# How to make condition dependent on trade execution

Tags: finance, pine-script

I want to make my script dependent on the `strategy.entry` being executed. Do anyone know how?

My code:

```
buy = crossover(delta, 0)

milliseconds_in_xdays = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 15

lastTrade = na
closetrd = time >= (lastTrade[15] + milliseconds_in_xdays)

if (buy)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long")
    ***if( strategy.long = true)*** NEED HELP HERE
        lastTrade := time

if (closetrd)
    strategy.close("Long")
    lastTrade := na
```

As you can see in my first `if` i'm setting the time and trying to close the trade after 15 days pass. I want the time to be set only if my "long" strategy is entered. Right now it is closing trades 15 days after any buy condition is met. I don't want this because my pyramiding is off.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering this doesn't exist yet and trading view is working on implementing a function that will return the number of days since last entry.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
barssince(change(strategy.position_size) > 0) == 15
```

as a condition.